# copy ssh key from windows to synology disk

Tags: ssh, scp, synology, rsa

I'm trying to set up a git server on my synology following [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/walkerjeffd/374750c366605cd5123d).
The step I'm stuck at is this:

```
copy public rsa key from local computer to gituser account on server
```

I use following command: `scp -r C:/.ssh/id_rsa.pub my-user-name@ip-adress/volume1/homes/gituser/.ssh`, which generates following output: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname c: Name or service not known`. 
Since I created a dir under `C:/.ssh` containing this file I don't know what to do. Can anybody help me on this one?

Answer (score 0):

Your need the directory path instead of using "C:"  scp thinks you are trying to copy from a server called "C". I don't have access to a Windows machine but try something like this `\desktop\myfolder\`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on  error, your  scp syntax looks incorrect.
scp -r "local_file_full_path" user_ID@hostname:/remote-server_path

colon( : ) is used for host specifier.